# how to transform interface to abstract by using javassist

Tags: aop, javassist

I am using javassist library for modify class files.

I want to modify interface to abstract class

for example, 
original :

```
public interface javax.servlet.Servlet {
 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException;
}
```

modified :

```
public abstract javax.servlet.Servlet {
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println(config.getServletContext().getServerInfo());
        callMethod(); // this is implemented original method
    }
}
```

How can i apply this solution like aop(before, after)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the **first problem with your approach** is that when you try to modify your `interface` using `Javassist` you are attempting to redefine an interface that has been already loaded by the class loader.

**One option** might be to do a bit of classloader tricks: create a new `classloader` that doesn't have your existing interface loaded (parent is the system classloader) and have `Javassist` load through that (use `aCtClass.toClass()` method that takes a `ClassLoader` argument). However is not really something I would do since to manage properly more than one `ClassLoader` is not that easy.

There might be a better way to achieve your goal, and **creating new classes might be a better design**. You could create a new class that implements everything you need and then extends the required interface.

Moreover I suggest you to **take also a look at [dynamic proxies](https://martinsdeveloperworld.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/implementing-dynamic-proxies-a-comparison/)** that could be an option as well. Their biggest advantage is that you don't need any 3rd party libraries to create them.

Comment: thx for kind reply : )
I want to apply dynamic proxies for all classes implement javax.servlet.Servlet
by using javassist.
It will be great idea to implement that :D

Comment: Consider upvote/set as correct this answer for future users need